# Mod want me to use standard flag in a question with open bounty

Tags: support

I flagged a question to mod because it has an open bounty. So, nothing else will work.

The question has already 2 CVs casted before the bounty.

It asks to recommend a good algorithm and also didn't show much effort.

But mod declined the flag saying

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

How the mod want me to use standard flag? which won't work

**Update**

This is my flag reason

> He want us to recommend an algorithm. But full details or Sample data is not given. In such case, this question seems to be closed/ on hold.

Comment: You wait until the bounty is over.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your flag was the following:

> He want us to recommend an algorithm. But full details or Sample data is not given. In such case, this question seems to be closed/ on hold.

You did not mention that the question had a bounty on it, and thus couldn't be closed by normal means. Moderators do not see bounty status when questions are displayed in our list of flags. We have to manually navigate to a question to see that, and even then we'd have to scroll all the way down to notice there was one on the question. If we're not given any indication that there's a bounty on a question, we won't know to look for one.

We get dozens of custom flags each day that tell us to close questions for one reason or another, when the person could have simply voted to close. Without the information about the bounty, your flag looked like one of those, which is why it was declined with one of our standard reasons.

Your follow-up flag provides the detail that was lacking in the first, so now we know why we have to act on it. As a result, I've refunded the bounty and closed the question.

Comment: I reflagged it with more details